# useEffect to rerender this component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to use useEffect to rerender `postList` (to make it render without the deleted post) when `postsCount` change, but I can't get it right. I tried to wrap everything inside useEffect but I couldn't execute `addEventListener("click", handlePost)` because I am using useEffect to wait for this component to mount first, before attaching the evenListener.

Parent component:

```
function Tabs() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const postsCount = useSelector((state) => state.posts.count);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("postsTab").addEventListener("click", handlePost);
  }, [handlePost]);

  const handlePost = async (e) => {
    const { data: { getPosts: postData }} = await refetchPosts();
    setPosts(postData);
    dispatch(postActions.getPostsReducer(postData));
  };

  const { data: FetchedPostsData, refetch: refetchPosts } = useQuery( FETCH_POSTS_QUERY, { manual: true });

  const [postList, setPostsList] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setPostsList(
      <Tab.Pane>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.Column>Title</Grid.Column>
          {posts.map((post) => (
              <AdminPostsList key={post.id} postId={post.id} />
            ))}
        </Grid>
      </Tab.Pane>
    );
    console.log("changed"); //it prints "changed" everytime postCount changes (or everytime I click delete), but the component doesn't remount
  }, [postsCount]);

  const panes = [
    { menuItem: { name: "Posts", id: "postsTab", key: "posts" }, render: () => postList }
  ];

  return (<Tab panes={panes} />);
}
```

child/AdminPostsList component:

```
function AdminPostsList(props) {
  const { postId } = props;
  const [deletePost] = useMutation(DELETE_POST_MUTATION, {variables: { postId } });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const deletePostHandler = async () => {
    dispatch(postActions.deletePost(postId));
    await deletePost();
  };
  return (
    <>
        <Button icon="delete" onClick={deletePostHandler}></Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

The Reducers

```
const PostSlice = createSlice({
  name: "storePosts",
  initialState: {
    content: [],
    count: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    getPostsReducer: (state, action) => {
      state.content = action.payload;
      state.count = action.payload.length
    },
    deletePost: (state, action) => {
      const id = action.payload
      state.content = current(state).content.filter((post) => (post.id !== id))
      state.count--
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: what is this ui library? I would like to check api of <Tab panes={panes}/> component myself. Looks weird this way.

Comment: @tomleb None taken, I am working on this project to learn react, this is why I am asking because I got stuck at this point and I can't figure out the mistake(s) I made to fix them. also. I very much appreciate your help point out the weird patterns and mistakes.

Comment: @linusw I am using Semantic UI, <Tab> is a ready-made component I am using from it

Comment: your code is run infinite re-render it is your question? if not describe more plz...

Comment: @AnujPanwar No it doesn't, All I want to do is to make <Tabs panes={panes}/> to rerender when I click the delete button, because when I do, I dispatch a reducerAction that increases `postCount`, this postCount I am using as useEffect (which should rerender the component and print `changed`) dependency, useEffect prints `changed` but it doesn't rerender the component.

Comment: You use libraries built on complex concepts but your code suggests you haven't mastered state management, event handling or react lifecycle. Unfortunately I can only recommend studying basics too.

Comment: @linusw I am still learning the basics, But I took it just a bit too far, lol. Thanks though, I think your comment made me rethink using the <Tab> component from semantic ui, I think it is the cause of the problem, If I just used a Buttons and divs instead, I think I would achieve what I want easily. I will back this component up and I will rewrite it using simple buttons and divs.

Comment: Your main problem is point where you are storing react elements in your state -`postList` state. I believe if  you do console.log of your state that you will end up with some react-specific objects in your state, because react element most likely will convert in js object and persist in that form inside your state, and not in form that you expected. That can cause a lot of bugs, so I suggest to rewrite and revisit some general patterns, because storing react elements inside your component state is definitely some sort of anti patter. State is for data only.

Comment: @MilosPavlovic I will defiantly recheck my reducers and your logic of think isn't wrong  at all, but if you notice I am destructuring data: { getPosts: postData } before sending it to getPostsReducer, I am sure that the payload of this reducer is just javascript array of objects, take a look: https://i.imgur.com/Trsn4oY.png

Comment: Part where you dispatch data to reducer seems okay. Problem is in second useEffect, where you do `setPostsList( <Tab.Pane>... </Tab.Pane>)`, and this is the place where you are storing react elements (<TabPane> and its chilren) in component state, which is wrong and can cause a lot of bugs. `postList` should be list, as name suggests, and not tree of react elements. I would say that second useEffect is completely unncecessary, you just need to select `posts` from redux state, and use it directly in you render part of the component.

Comment: @MilosPavlovic I used useEffect trying to make the component rerender on postCount when postcount changes, but it used to be a regular variable.
as for maping over the posts from the state, in this case I couldn't because I am setting the state after the Tab of posts mounts, notice `handlePost` is a onClick evenListener attached to the pane title, since I couldn't find a way to attach it directly to the element `const panes = [{ menuItem: { name: "Posts", id: "postsTab", key: "posts" }, render: () => postList }];` I had to use useEffect to remount it after the component is mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's discuss what I did wrong for the future reader:

1. There is no need to use this weird spaghetti

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.getElementById("postsTab").addEventListener("click", handlePost);
}, [handlePost]);
const panes = [
  { menuItem: { name: "Posts", id: "postsTab", key: "posts" }, render: () => postList }
];
```

for I could've used a `<Menu.Item onClick={handleClick}>Posts</Menu.Item>` to attach the `onClick` directly.

2. I had to use `useEffect` to monitor `posts` dependency, but `.map()` will automatically update its content if the array I am mapping had any changes so there is no need to use it use `useEffect` in this context.
3. I think I can use lifting state to `setPosts` from the child component and the change will trigger `.map()` to remap and pop the deleted element, but I couldn't find a way to so, so I am using a combination of redux (to store the posts) and `useEffect` to dispatch the `posts` to the store than I am mapping over the stored redux element, idk if this is the best approach but this is all I managed to do.
4. The most important thing I didn't notice when I almost tried everything is, I must update apollo-cache when adding/deleting a post, by using `proxy.readQuery`
   this is how I did it

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const handlePosts = async () => {
    const { data: { getPosts: postData } } = await refetchPosts();
    setPosts(postData);
  };

  const handlePosts = async () => {
    const { data } = await refetchPosts();
    setPosts(data.getPosts);
  };

  // Using useEffect temporarily to make it work.
  // Will replace it with an lifting state when refactoring later.
  useEffect(() => {
    posts && dispatch(postsActions.PostsReducer(posts))
  }, [posts]);
```

```
  const [deletePost] = useMutation(DELETE_POST_MUTATION, {
    update(proxy) {
      let data = proxy.readQuery({
        query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY,
      });
      // Reconstructing data, filtering the deleted post 
      data = { getPosts: data.getPosts.filter((post) => post.id !== postId) };
      // Rewriting apollo-cache
      proxy.writeQuery({ query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY, data });
    },
    onError(err) {
      console.log(err);
    },
    variables: { postId },
  });

  const deletePostHandler = async () => {
    deletePost();
    dispatch(postsActions.deletePost(postId))
  };
```

Thanks to @[Anuj Panwar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17752587/anuj-panwar) @[Milos Pavlovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19397457/milos-pavlovic) for helping out, kudos to @[Cptkrush](https://www.reddit.com/user/Cptkrush/) for bringing the store idea into my attention

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let discuss this in separate comment. Key point is to decouple posts logic from wrapper component(Tabs). You should create component dedicated only to posts and render it in wrapper. Like that you can easily isolate all posts-related logic in posts-related component, for example to avoid attaching some listeners from wrapper(because it is not intuitive what you are doing and who listens for what because button is not in that same component). In separated component you will have only one useEffect, to fetch posts, and you will have one selector(to select posts from redux), and then just use that selection to output content from component.
That part `<Tab panes={...} />` was the source of most of your problems, because like that you are forced to solve everything above `<Tab../>` and then just to pass it, which is not best practice in you case since it can be too complicated(especially in case when you could have multiple tabs). That is why you need to decouple and to create tab-specific components.

This would be an idea of how you should refactor it:

```
function PostsTab() {
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts?.content ?? []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Here dispatch action to load your posts
    // With this approach, when you have separated component for PostsTab no need to attach some weird event listeners, you can do everything here in effect
    // This should be triggered only once
    // You can maybe introduce 'loading' flag in your reducer so you can display some loaders for better UX
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Here use Tab components in order to create desired tab */}
      <Tab.Pane>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.Column>Title</Grid.Column>
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <AdminPostsList key={post.id} postId={post.id} />
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Tab.Pane>
    </div>
  );
}

function Tabs() {
  return (
    <div>
      <PostsTab/>
      {/** HERE you can add more tabs when you need to
      * Point is to create separate component per tab so you can isolate and maintain tab state in dedicated component
      and to avoid writing all logic here in wrapper component
      * As you can see there is no need to attach any weird listener, everything related to posts is moved to PostsTab component
      */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much  Milos, I really appreciate your help. I have conceded that a lot but I didn't do it because I am already nesting almost 3 components inside each other, I have the main page > tabs > AdminUserList (which has the delete button and I am mapping throw Posts and returning it for each Post) and finally I have > AdminEditPost (I am using this component to open a modal to edit post content). So I thought enough with nesting.

Comment: but I will rewrite the component again using  your approach and I will come back tomorrow to update the question.

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to ask for any additional help!

Comment: You could probably still use `return <Tab panes={panes} />` solution, but with this approach panes list should be smth like `const panes = [
    { menuItem: { name: "Posts", id: "postsTab", key: "posts" }, render: () => <PostsTab /> }
  ];`

Comment: I found out that I could render a regular `<Menu.Item>` instead of obj in `const panes = [{menuItem: <Menu.Item>Value</Menu.Item>}] , this way I have successfully passed `onClick={handlePost}` directly to the `Menu.Item` and I got rid of this weird `useEffect.. ..addEventListener("click", handlePost)`. now I can wrap everything inside useEffect w/o any problems. I am still not in the clear about why <Tab.Pane> doesn't rerender, but at least I have fixed something. and tomorrow I will try your approach, its been almost 10 hours trying to fix this.